# How to use context.getNamedDispatcher with the Guice Servlet Extension

Tags: java, servlets, guice

I am trying migrate a servlet-project to use Guice 3.0-rc2 (from maven central) and its servlet extension. I already migrated another project where I had the same problem:

Since Guice renders the `web.xml` basically useless, I have no idea where to define my servlets names. The codebase makes quite heavy use of `ServletContext#getNamedDispatcher("name")` and I would like to change as little as possible. The first codebase used `getNamedDispatcher` only once, so I was able work around that.

The Servlets in question are not listening to any path, so using `getRequesetDispatcher` won't do.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

One of the big things Guice tries to do is move away from using unreliable `String` identifiers to using actual Java types to do things. While guice-servlet managed servlets do have names (the `toString()` of the `Key` they are bound as), I don't think the `ServletContext` is aware of them.

One option that may work for you is to actually inject the servlet(s) you want to be able to pass requests to and do it directly yourself:

```
@Singleton
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
  private final TestServlet2 testServlet2;

  @Inject public TestServlet(TestServlet2 testServlet2) {
    this.testServlet2 = testServlet2;
  }

  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                       HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    testServlet2.doGet(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
  }
}
```

For this to work, you do need to register the servlets in your `ServletModule`... I think you can `serve("").with(TestServlet2.class)` in order to not have it map to any URL.

Comment: Sorry this won't work for me. I specifically need a way to determine / assign the names of the Servlets, because they are also part of some routing-rule-engine I'd rather not touch.

Comment: @msung: I'm guessing this involves routing the requests through some filters to the servlets and such? If not, one option might be binding the servlets using a `MapBinder` (from the multibinding extension) using the same names as they had in web.xml before and then looking them up in the `Map` rather than using a `RequestDispatcher`. Otherwise, I think what you want is probably just outside the scope of what guice-servlet is designed to do.

Comment: I worked around the issue by mapping the previously used servlet names to their classes. As far as I can tell, looking up the servlets works. Is there a particular reason why you chose to use method injection in your example? Would injecting the servlet directly or getInstance(YourServlet.class) not work?

Comment: @msung: My example uses constructor injection and injects the servlet directly, so I'm not quite sure what you're asking. `injector.getInstance` can of course be used to get an instance of any object that can be injected but you generally shouldn't be using the `injector` directly in most applications... only in very specific cases where a class needs to be able to do some kind of dynamic lookup, and even then there are generally other options.